# postings nextPosition returns nul, freq returns 0, payload() returns null

Tags: lucene, payload

I made simplest index with one document using LuceneTestCase. My goal is to write numbers to payload for each position of each term, that will be used in custom scoring formula implemented in custom Query/Scorer.

I used SimpleTextCodec and checked, that freq, positions and payload was really written to index.

But when I'm reading freq from the PostingEnum it returns 0, payload() returns null, nextPosition() throws an exception:

```
  java.lang.AssertionError: got line=field model

  at __randomizedtesting.SeedInfo.seed([D334C9D1B5C155E3:2AAE4BE5481F4C8F]:0)
  at
       org.apache.lucene.codecs.simpletext.SimpleTextFieldsReader$SimpleTextPostings  Enum.nextPosition(SimpleTextFieldsReader.java:455)
```

Here is how I'm reading the postings in the custom Query:

```
for (String field: fieldScores.keySet()) {
final Terms fieldTerms = reader.terms(field);
if (fieldTerms == null) {
    continue;
}

if (!fieldTerms.hasPositions())
    throw new IllegalStateException("Index does not contain positions");

if (!fieldTerms.hasPayloads())
    throw new IllegalStateException("Index does not contain payloads");

final TermsEnum te = fieldTerms.iterator();
for (int j = 0; j < terms.length; j++) {
    final Term t = terms[j];

    if (t.field().equals(field) && te.seekExact(t.bytes())) {
        PostingsEnum postingsEnum = te.postings(null, PostingsEnum.ALL);

        int pos = postingsEnum.nextPosition();
        BytesRef payload = postingsEnum.getPayload();
        // assert payload.bytesEquals(new BytesRef(new byte[]{1}));

        // TODO: use payload in scoring formula
        fldScorers.add(new ConstTermScorer(this, t,
                fieldScores.get(field) * termScores.get(t.text()),
 postingsEnum));
        }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the reason. nextPosition(), freq() and payload() return 0 (or null) values because postingsEnum (iterator) is just created and not positioned on concrete document yet. postingsEnum.nextDoc() wasn't called and postingsEnum.docID() is -1. Stupid situation, but it would be better may be if nextPosition(), freq() and payload() would check postingsEnum.docID.